# Will alone bin log ignore DB mysql helps in slave read only mode

Tags: mysql-5.6, percona-server

Please correct me if I'm wrong . 
**In Master - Slave setup:**

Case 1:

> If I didn't  enable Binlog ignore DB mysql: In future ill lose all
>   users created in master node incase of master crash or slave to master
>   and master to slave scenario.

Case 2:

> If I did enable binlog ignore DB mysql and an user has  all
>   privileges, he can directly connect to slave DB[if he is fishy], and
>   manipulate data in slave which causes inconsistency.

[image: In Master create a user and database]
[image: In slave able to create new table with same user]
How to over come this scenario? I'm new to this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After series of testing.. this scenario only happens if we grant all privileges on every database **(*.*)**[ I think it will assume this specific user as root privileged and allows to access any database. In any other scenario it will reject with below error.

```
*ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement*
```